# How to use sauce labs v1/analytics/test API?

Tags: curl, saucelabs

I need to use sauces labs API: /v1/analytics/tests api, and my curl command is:

```
curl -u "pmchao:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" --location \--request GET "https://api.us-west-1.saucelabs.com/v1/analytics/tests?start=2023-04-01T12:00:00Z&end=2023-04-15T12:00:00Z&size=10&from=10&build=build-123"
```

but my return has two status code:

[image: my output]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: It says HTTP Error 404 "The request resources is not found" I am not sure what it is referring to. I have chosen the time where I have some test results.

Answer (score 0):

Can you rotate your access key for Sauce Labs? Its in the screenshot.

And if you're still experiencing this issue can we strip the request down to the bare minimum? The fact that a curl "bad missing url" error is thrown means there's some kind of syntax issue usually.

Try this

````
curl -u "$SAUCE_USERNAME:$SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY" --request GET "https://api.us-west-1.saucelabs.com/v1/analytics/tests"```
````